# How to use Perf in Clion remote mode?

Tags: clion, remote-debugging, perf

## Question

I want to use Perf when Clion connects to a remote server. I want to know how to set it up? Perf has been installed in the remote server (Ubuntu). But the configuration path of Perf can only detect the local paht (windows), not set to the server path.

I saw that Clion said that Profiling in remote mode has been used since the 2021.2 EAP version, but didnot say how to set the path to the remote server path.

## Version

- local: windows 10; remote server: Ubuntu20.04
- Clion 2022.2.4

I look forward to your answers, thank you very much!

The SSH configuration, toolchain, and cmake have all been set up successfully. I can already develop remotely. The source code is stored in the local, mapped to the server and updated in real time.